# Descriptive hostnames for server farm

Tags: hosting, hostname

Can someone give some insight to 4 fully qualified hostnames I can use for our new server setup. Assume the name of the website is helloworld.com We have the following:

- A Webserver
- A Failover Server
- A Storage Server
- A Database Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your expansion plan for the future?

A generic set up that allows for scalability (more machines in the future) would look like this:

web1.helloworld.com
standby1.helloworld.com
files1.helloworld.com
db1.helloworld.com

If the failover is for the web server, you may want to try: web2.helloworld.com or backup2.helloworld.com or something like that.

(You may start things with 1 or 0.)

Comment: This is smarter, starting at 1 for everything :-)

Comment: You may not need it right away, but I'd pad those numbers with one or more leading zeros.

Comment: Dennis, you're so right. I often forget to do that with other stuff and then have to write a script to fix it. Thanks. :-).

Answer (score 0):

- webserver: www.helloworld.com perhaprs?
- failover: Failover for what, www?
  Then maybe www2.helloworld.com
- Storage: storage.helloworld.com
- database: db.helloworld.com

Comment: Do I need the www for a hostname?

Comment: Are you talking about names in DNS for the external network, or internal host names? You can add lots of "names" in DNS to refer to a server but have one name for the actual machine...